# How to create a new user with Postman and assign group in keycloak?

Tags: json, post, postman, keycloak

I have this JSON to create a new user, which works for me, but it doesn't assign the group declared in the groups `"groups":["APIs"]` tab to the user

JSON:

```
{ 
   "username":"1prueba@demo.com",
   "firstName":"1pruebattributesFN",
   "lastName":"1pruebattributesAP",
   "email":"1prueba@demo.com",
   "enabled":true,
   "groups":["APIs"],
   "credentials":[ 
      { 
         "temporary": false,
         "type":"password",
         "value":"1234"
      }
   ],
   "attributes":
      { 
         "EmailVerifiedvn":"TRUE",
         "Enabledvn":"TRUE",
         "Entity":"[{\"id\":\"3411982108\",\"name\":\"3411982108 - Claro Home  PAGO APP 2\"}]",
         "State":"Activo",
         "UserCreateDate":"202001031650Z",
         "UserLastModifiedDate":"202001031655Z",
         "UserStatus":"CONFIRMED"
      }
}
```

The user is created but does not assign the group to the user.

In my keycloak I have declared 3 groups:

[image: groups created]

Answer (score 8):

**Update:**

In Keycloak 17 it can be assigned directly. See Hernaldo's answer.

**Old way:**

I don't think it works that way, you can use below API to assign a user to a group:

```
    Request URL: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}/groups/{groupId}
    Request Method: PUT
```

Source: [Keycloak Admin Rest API Docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/)

Comment: Is there any way to assign list of users to a group ??

Comment: @Lisa I don't think there is an endpoint that supports list insertion, you may have to use a loop for that.

Answer (score 3):

In keycloak 17 it can be assigned directly:

First you have to create the group "mygroup" inside Keycloak

```
POST
http://<ip>:8080/admin/realms/master/users
```

Header

```
Name: Authorization
Value: Bearer <Admin cli Access token>
```

Body raw data

```
{"enabled":true,"username":"usergrupo","email":"usergrupo@gmail.com","firstName":"functest","lastName":"functest", "groups":["migrupo", "miotrogrupo"], "credentials":[{"type":"password","value":"123","temporary":false}]}
```

Finally the associated user will be created in that group

Documentation:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/#_userrepresentation

Comment: What did you assign values of groups? Is it the name of the group, or the ID?

Answer (score 2):

```
// Step 1 - Create User 
// Step 2 - Join Group(s) to this user

javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = KeycloakBuilder.builder().build().realm("your-realm-name").users().create(userRepresentation);
if (response != null && response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() == Family.SUCCESSFUL) 
{
    KeycloakBuilder.builder().build().realm("your-realm-name").users().get(CreatedResponseUtil.getCreatedId(response)).joinGroup("your-group-id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing to be aware when you are sending payload for creating users with assigned groups. Groups value is array of `GROUP_PATHs`. Example:

```
{ 
  ...,
  "groups":[GROUP_PATH,...],
  ...
}
```

so no `GROUP_ID` or `GROUP_NAME` but `GROUP_PATH` should be used! I have lost a ton of time until I found the issue why groups were not there.